# Not able to build a Qt project in visual studio 2005

Tags: c++, qt4

When i am building my project in visual studio 2005 its end up with the following error 
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'QtCored.lib'.
Please let me know where i am failing .

Comment: Probably you aren't correctly linking to Qt. You  may want to consider [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7231764/1714661) as a reference to linking against QT.

Comment: Let us go the easy way. Do you have a qmake makefile?

Comment: No .. I have just followed the following way ..Open the VS 2005 ->File->new->project->QtProject...

Comment: can you please say how do i set QTDIR, PATH and QMAKESPEC ?

Comment: I have only 
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

 return a.exec();
}
when i am compiling this its showing the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we are integrating Qt 4.7.3 with visual studio 2005 and tries to create one Qt project in IDE , its giving a fatal error stating Qtcored.lib is missing . Actually if you go ..\Qt\4.7.3\lib folder there is nothing called Qtcored.lib ,But there is Qtcored4.lib . I think they have renamed it (not sure) . Now goto projproperties->linker->input->additionaldependency and remove Qtcored.lib from there and add Qtcored4.lib. Now if you build the project it will work fine ..

Cheerssss.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Visual studio is not able to find the library file QtCored.lib. You have to specify the library path of it in visual studio settings.